# Windows 10 domain machine won't use NTLMv2 auth

Tags: windows-10, security, samba, active-directory

I have several Windows 10 machines on a corporate domain which are unable to mount an SMB share.  Other Windows clients outside the domain can mount the share just fine.  The Samba server allows only NTLMv2 authentication by default.  If I change this to allow NTLMv1 then it all works, but I prefer not to do this.  I found this setting in the Local Security Policy on the clients:

**Network security: Lan Manager authentication level**: Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated

I believe that might be the problem, but it's grayed out so I can't change it (probably because it's inherited from the domain).  I'm trying to understand why it doesn't try to negotiate NTLMv2?

With Wireshark, the failed login flow looks like this:

```
Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: CDX-MV2U-00012\storageadmin
Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

From samba debug log (level 5) here is where it should try v2 but it doesn't:

```
[2021/12/15 16:03:06.442885,  1] ../../librpc/ndr/ndr.c:433(ndr_print_debug)
       authenticate: struct AUTHENTICATE_MESSAGE
          Signature                : 'NTLMSSP'
          MessageType              : NtLmAuthenticate (3)
          LmChallengeResponseLen   : 0x0018 (24)
          LmChallengeResponseMaxLen: 0x0018 (24)
          LmChallengeResponse      : *
              LmChallengeResponse      : union ntlmssp_LM_RESPONSE_with_len(case 24)
              v1: struct LM_RESPONSE
                  Response                 : c892ccae7c9ba0c300000000000000000000000000000000
          NtChallengeResponseLen   : 0x0018 (24)
          NtChallengeResponseMaxLen: 0x0018 (24)
          NtChallengeResponse      : *
              NtChallengeResponse      : union ntlmssp_NTLM_RESPONSE_with_len(case 24)
              v1: struct NTLM_RESPONSE
                  Response                 : 3331477ae6795d22ae6f4cbee722dff339d6df9df49cef7e
          DomainNameLen            : 0x001c (28)
          DomainNameMaxLen         : 0x001c (28)
          DomainName               : *
              DomainName               : 'CDX-MV2U-00012'
          UserNameLen              : 0x0018 (24)
          UserNameMaxLen           : 0x0018 (24)
          UserName                 : *
              UserName                 : 'storageadmin'
          WorkstationLen           : 0x001c (28)
          WorkstationMaxLen        : 0x001c (28)
          Workstation              : *
              Workstation              : 'LANOS-GENERAL2'
          EncryptedRandomSessionKeyLen: 0x0010 (16)
          EncryptedRandomSessionKeyMaxLen: 0x0010 (16)
          EncryptedRandomSessionKey: *
              EncryptedRandomSessionKey: DATA_BLOB length=16
  [0000] 9F 92 82 09 16 F9 93 8C   BC A9 E8 0F BA 7E D5 6C   ........ .....~.l
          NegotiateFlags           : 0xe2888215 (3800597013)
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM    
                 1: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET   
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN   
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SEAL   
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_DATAGRAM
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_LM_KEY 
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NETWARE
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM   
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NT_ONLY
                 0: NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS        
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_DOMAIN_SUPPLIED
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_WORKSTATION_SUPPLIED
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_THIS_IS_LOCAL_CALL
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
                 0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN
                 0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER
                 0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SHARE
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
                 0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_IDENTIFY
                 0: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_NON_NT_SESSION_KEY
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128    
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
                 1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56     
          Version: struct ntlmssp_VERSION
              ProductMajorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MAJOR_VERSION_10 (10)
              ProductMinorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MINOR_VERSION_0 (0)
              ProductBuild             : 0x4a61 (19041)
              Reserved: ARRAY(3)
                  [0]                      : 0x00 (0)
                  [1]                      : 0x00 (0)
                  [2]                      : 0x00 (0)
              NTLMRevisionCurrent      : NTLMSSP_REVISION_W2K3 (15)
```

Comment: Hold on – if they're in domain, why are they using NTLM and not Kerberos in the first place?

Comment: because the Samba server is not in domain?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/879166/use-ntlmv2-authentication-with-samba